# Uchiṣṭa Ganapati Suktam in Atharvana veda

Tags: vedas, reference-request, atharva-veda, ganapati

Does anyone know where in the Atharvana Veda we can find Uchiṣṭa Gaṇeśa/Gaṇapati suktam?

Comment: Isn't Uchiṣṭa Gaṇapati a tantric deity?

Comment: Do you mean this: http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/atharvaveda-samhitas/shaunaka-samhita/kanda-11-sukta-007/

Comment: Thank you, yes that seems it.

Comment: @Proxy it would be nice if you could post an answer.

Comment: Any chances to have a translitered text of this Sukta?

Comment: @LuckyPashu here is a pretty bad quality text, but meanings of sukta 7 of kanda 11 ucchista Bhrhama suktam in hindi. https://archive.org/details/AtharvaVedaBhashyamTrivediKshemakarandas/%22Atharva%20veda%20bhashyam%20kANDa%2011.%20%20Trivedi%2C%20kshemakarandas.%201917.%20sanskrit.%20Veda.%20255%20pgs.%22/page/n159/mode/2up

Comment: amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some say there were 7 *shakhas* (schools) in Atharvaveda, while *Caraṇavyuha* lists nine shakhas: *paippalāda, stauda, mauda,  śaunakīya, jājala, jalada, brahmavada, devadarśa and cāraṇavaidyā*. Out of it only two have survived, they are the *paippalāda* and *śaunakīya*.

*Saunakīya* consists of kandas. These contain a lot of mantras, suktas and even indrajals for many types of works. The kanda 11 sukta 7 consists of *uchishta Brhama sukta* which forms the foundation of ucchishta Ganpati upasana. It can be found here: http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/atharvaveda-samhitas/shaunaka-samhita/kanda-11-sukta-007/

ucchishta Ganpati is the tantric form of Ganpati and is infact one of the 32 forms of Ganapati. Ucchishta literally means "polluted by saliva" and represents 'leftovers'. The food which is contaminated by saliva. It is vamamarga, ucchishta Ganpati is shown in union with his shakti- "Hastipashachini" which is 'Tamasik' by nature. It is always better to do the upasana in guidance of a guru. There are many mantras and stotras of ucchishta Ganpati like ucchishta Ganpati kavacham etc.

The Bhava artha in hindi can be found [here](https://archive.org/details/AtharvaVedaBhashyamTrivediKshemakarandas/%22Atharva%20veda%20bhashyam%20kANDa%2011.%20%20Trivedi%2C%20kshemakarandas.%201917.%20sanskrit.%20Veda.%20255%20pgs.%22/page/n159/mode/2up).